# PHP limit for loop iterations of folder item listing

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to limit the iterations of a foreach loop to display only 4 items contained in a folder, instead of all, however at the moment it keeps displaying all items:

```
<?php
$dir    = 'images';
$images = scandir($dir);
$i=0;
foreach($images as $file){
    if ($i == 4) {
        break;
    }
    $pos = strpos($file, '-s.jpg');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo '<a href="/images/'.$file.'"><img src="/images/'.$file.'"/></a>';
    } // end if strpos
    $i++;
} // end foreach
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `foreach()` but `for()` instead? And maybe `glob()` instead of `scandir()`.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` loop in php iterate through all the array. So you need to make a `for` loop to make it work. This way should be good :

```
<?php
$dir    = 'images';
$images = scandir($dir);
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $pos = strpos($images[$i], '-s.jpg');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo '<a href="/images/'.$images[$i].'"><img src="/images/'.$images[$i].'"/></a>';
    } // end if strpos
} // end for
?>
```

Comment: this only displays 1 image, instead of 4

Comment: this is not normal. It iterates 4 times so should work well. If not, it doesn't come from the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works, had to include the $i++ inside the strpos check, and change to "if($i>4){...}":

```
<?php
$dir    = 'images';
$images = scandir($dir);
$i=1;
foreach($images as $file){
    if ($i>4){
      break;
    }
    $pos = strpos($file, '-s.jpg');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo '<a href="/images/'.$file.'"><img src="/images/'.$file.'"/></a>';
        $i++;
    } // end if strpos
} // end foreach
?>
```